# wpdb query - How to display the result even if values are missing?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have read that if there is data missing from the '$wpdb->get_results' query, then the result will be completely empty.

My query is as follows:

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results("

SELECT 
( SELECT guid FROM ch_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value ) AS thumbnail, ID, post_title, post_name, SUBSTR(post_content, 20) AS content, post_date, t.name AS category

FROM ch_posts, ch_postmeta m

JOIN ch_term_relationships tr
JOIN ch_terms t ON t.term_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id 
JOIN ch_term_taxonomy tx ON tr.term_taxonomy_id = tx.term_taxonomy_id

WHERE post_status = 'publish'
AND post_author = $user_ID
AND post_type = 'product'
AND ch_posts.ID = m.post_id
AND m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id'
AND tr.object_id = ch_posts.ID
AND tx.taxonomy = 'product_cat'
");
```

then

```
foreach ($results as $result) {     }
```

Because my post has a missing 'thumbnail' record, the entire results set does not get displayed. Is it possible to modify my query to show the results that are found and just ignore the ones that are missing? Or replace the missing values with something else?

I have tried using CASE, But to no avail.

Any help will be most welcome

Comment: coalesce(Column,ValueIfNull)

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Any reason for not using WP_Query?

Answer (score 0):

1st, your query is not full. Show the whole query. 2nd, you're getting thumbnail url in a wrong way. 3rd, join should not be inner for tables that are for getting thumbnail. Example of getting 20 last posts with thumbnail (NULL is none)

```
SELECT `posts`.`ID` AS `ID`, `posts`.`post_title` AS `title`, `posts`.`post_name` AS `slug`, `posts`.`post_content` AS `content`, `posts`.`post_excerpt` AS `excerpt`, `thumb_link` FROM `wp_posts` AS `posts`
LEFT JOIN (select `thumb`.`post_id` AS `object_id`, `thumbs_link`.`meta_value` AS `thumb_link` from `wp_postmeta` AS `thumb` 
LEFT JOIN`wp_postmeta` AS thumbs_link ON (`thumbs_link`.`post_id` = `thumb`.`meta_value`) 
AND `thumbs_link`.meta_key = "_wp_attached_file" WHERE `thumb`.`meta_key` = '_thumbnail_id' 
GROUP BY `thumb`.`post_id` ) AS `thumb`  ON `thumb`.`object_id` = `posts`.`ID`
WHERE `posts`.`post_status` = 'publish'
ORDER BY `posts`.`ID` DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: Performance benefits aside, in the absence of any aggregating functions, a GROUP BY clause is generally inappropriate.